# Why is this printing the previous output?

Tags: c, file-io, stdin

I'm working on my implementation of the cat linux command. For the moment, it can read from the standard input when no arguments are passed after the command and read from multiples files sequentially but when '-' is passed as an argument is prints the previous output instead before reading from the standard input in some cases.

For example, if you pass - file1.txt - file2.txt - as argument, everything works as expected. It reads from the standard input, outputs the contents of file1.txt, reads from stdin again and so on. But if i remove the first '-', in other words, if the first argument is a file, it ouputs the contents of file1.txt then, reads from stdin, then prints the contents of the second file and then, instead of reading from stdin like before, the first time it reads from stdin it ouputs the contents of the second file again followed by the input, it only starts to function normally after that.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

void readStdin(){
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  while(fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin)){ //reads from the standard input and prints the input
    char *content = malloc(sizeof(char*)*BUF_SIZE);
    if(content == NULL){ //failed to allocate memory
      exit(1);
    }
    strcat(content, buffer);
    //printf("buffer: %s", buffer);
    //printf("content: %s", content);
    printf(content);

    memset(&content[0], 0, sizeof(*content));
    free(content);

    //printf("bufferEND: %s", buffer);
    //printf("contentEND: %s", content);
  }
}

void readArgs(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE* fp;
  char ch;
  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    if (*argv[i] == '-'){
      readStdin();
      clearerr(stdin);
    }

    //else if ()
    else {
      fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
      if (fp==NULL){ //in case the file doesn't exist
        printf("%s: No such file or directory\n", argv[i]);
        exit(1);
      }
      while ((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        putchar(ch);
      }
  //    fflush(stdin);

      fclose(fp);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if (argc<2){
    readStdin();
    return 0;
  }
  readArgs(argc, argv);
  return 0;
}
```

Any hint?

EDIT: if i pass another file followed by another '-', after reading from stdin in the faulty way described above, not only it behvaves the same but it doesnt print the first character of the previous output

Answer (score 0):

Your code here expects '-' as an argument

```
if (*argv[i] == '-'){
  readStdin();
  clearerr(stdin);
}
```

Your program only calls `readStdin()` when it receives '-' as an argument, and outputs the argument file otherwise.

When you pass `- file1.txt - file2.txt -`, these are 5 arguments (6 including the program name) telling your program "read, output file1.txt, read, output file2.txt, read"
Thus, when you remove the first `-`, you are also removing the first "read", and you are instead telling your program to "output file1.txt, read, output file2.txt, read"

Answer (score 0):

In the fine tradition of this site's name, I suspect you are overwriting the stack. When you allocate memory with malloc() it is uninitialized, which means it could contain anything. As a result, when you do strcat(content,buffer), it will append the contents of buffer[] after the last non-null character in content[], but there is no way to know where that last non-null character will be. It could easily be beyond the last byte of content[]. Welcome to the world of C.

> On reflection, content[] is on the heap, so you would not overwrite the stack after all, but I'm leaving the text here because you really should fix they way you are working with content[].

There are some other problems with this code, probably because you're used to working in other languages. For example, printf(content) is not a good idea because the first argument to printf() is interpreted as a format string. If they data in the file contains anything like "%X" where X is a printf format specifier, printf() will interpret it as part of its formatting language. This could lead to a crash and is also a common source of security vulnerabilities since whoever crafts the input can use format specifiers to read/write arbitrary locations in memory.

Usually in C, weird or non-deterministic behavior is due to memory handling errors. You might want to install the 'valgrind' tool, which can help you find such things.

Also I don't see why you are going through the whole malloc/strcat/memset/free thing with content[]. It would be simpler just to print the buffer[] directly, but maybe you have some future plans for what you want to do with the data?